# Конвертировать HTML в JSON

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек

Есть ли конвертер из HTML в JSON, написанный на Python?
**Не нужен** онлайн конвертер или конвертер на JS.
В интернете куча конвертеров, написанных на JS, но ни одного не нашел на питоне.

Comment: Может быть, из XML в JSON? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10201405/7485582

Comment: @Кирилл Малышев HTML в JSON. На html написаны странички веб сайтов, его не спутать с xml

Comment: приведите пример "онлайн конвертера" или "конвертера на JS" из HTML в JSON?

Comment: @Jack_oS в поиске сразу первый сайт. Повторюсь мне не нужен на js

Comment: Онлайн конвертер: https://toolslick.com/conversion/data/html-to-json

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43469412/7485582

Comment: @Кирилл Малышев нужен json, а не html в обычном словаре. Я Вам отправил сайт в качестве примера перевода из html в json. По аналогии такого сайта есть конвертеры на питоне?

Answer (score 0):

Я 50/50 пока сам понял как пользоваться, но это походу нужная вам библиотека:

[html2json 0.2.4.1](https://pypi.org/project/html2json/#description)

Comment: я установил эту библиотеку еще до того как задал вопрос, но документацию к ней я не нашел

Comment: Ну так можно поискать ролики на ютубе, есть же не только документация